# Is it secure to store on client's device AWS Temporary Credentials (STS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, access-token, credentials, amazon-cognito

I wanted to ask you if it is secure to **store** AWS temporary credentials (`Access Key ID`, `Secret Access Key`, `Session Token`) on mobile device that calls an API?
Many sources describes this as necessary part of authorization process. According to mentioned below AWS resources images:

[image: Retreiving temporary credentials]

[image: Federating access to AWS resources]

I'm speaking of credentials that can be obtained by `assumeRoleWithWebIdentity` or `getCredentialsForIdentity`.

Isn't it more secure to use JWT tokents instead to prevent hacking those credentials and obtain access to secured by them resources?

Comment: It seems like *obtain access to secured resources* implies that these credentials have access to resources that they shouldn't... but why do you need to "store" them when you can keep them in memory or request them again when needed?  You may have a good point, but it isn't clear yet (to me, anyway).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've clarified question. 
The point is, that we can ask for those credentials every time we want access resources they secure, but it's not very efficient. From my experience every RDS `SELECT` preceded by `getCredentialsForIdentity` or `assumeRoleWithWebIdentity` takes about 1s which is way too long time for simple `SELECT`. Thus storing those credentials in a memory of the client's device seems good idea, but there comes security issues eg. as mentioned hacking them (due to precence of `accessKeyId`, `secretAccessKey` and `sessionToken`).

Answer (score 0):

The credentials you get from STS are no different (at a high level) than JWT tokens. They are both temporary, and if a 'hacker' were to obtain either type of credential, the result would be the same. A key benefit of using temporary credentials in general is that if/when they are compromised, they are only valid for a short amount of time (usually an hour).

Storing temporary credentials on the device is a separate topic, but JWT tokens would not be any different that the STS session credentials.

I don't have any links, but I'm sure there are good public discussions and docs on storing session credentials in apps on devices.